# Angular 13 with ngrx and OAuth2 issue creating an effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

So I'm following this example, though it is an earlier version of Angular and ngrx.[NGRX Authentication in Angular with asp.net core](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2020/05/29/authentication-in-angular-with-ngrx-and-asp.net-core/)

My Auth.action.ts file is:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const checkAuth = createAction('[Auth] checkAuth');
export const checkAuthComplete = createAction(
  '[Auth] checkAuthComplete',
  props<{ isLoggedIn: boolean }>()
);
export const login = createAction('[Auth] login');
export const loginComplete = createAction(
  '[Auth] loginComplete',
  props<{ profile: any; isLoggedIn: boolean }>()
);
export const logout = createAction('[Auth] logout');
export const logoutComplete = createAction('[Auth] logoutComplete');
```

In my auth.service.ts file I have a method:

```
checkAuth() {
   return this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth();
}
```

Then in mu auth.effects.ts file I have:

```
import * as fromAuthActions from '../Actions/auth.actions';
.......
checkauth$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromAuthActions.checkAuth),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.authService
      .checkAuth()
      .pipe(
        map((isLoggedIn) => fromAuthActions.checkAuthComplete({ isLoggedIn }))
      )
   )
 )
);
```

It errors on isLoggedIn of fromAuthActions.checkAuthComplete({ isLoggedIn }))

stating that

> 'LoginResponse' is not assignable to type boolean.

I've been looking for a while now, but cannot figure out what I need to change.

Comment: What exactly does the `checkAuth` method return? If it's not just the boolean, but some object, then that's your issue.

Comment: @mat.hudak The LoginResponse is an object in the angular-auth-oidc-client library, but it's not easy to work out what makes up that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the angular oidc docs - https://angular-auth-oidc-client.com/docs/documentation/public-api#forcerefreshsessioncustomparams----configid-string
[image]

This means that `authObj` is not a `boolean` but a `LoginResponse` object.
The effect should use the `isAuthenticated` property:

```
import * as fromAuthActions from '../Actions/auth.actions';
.......
checkauth$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromAuthActions.checkAuth),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.authService
      .checkAuth()
      .pipe(
        map((response) => fromAuthActions.checkAuthComplete({ isLoggedIn: response.isAuthenticated ))
      )
   )
 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the return type is some sort of an object, you should either get the value of it or use it as a boolean.

```typescript
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromAuthActions.checkAuth),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.authService
      .checkAuth()
      .pipe(
        map((authObj) => fromAuthActions.checkAuthComplete({ isLoggedIn: !!authObj}))
        // or assign some value from within: { isLoggedIn: authObj.someFlag}
      )
   )
 )
);
```

You have defined in the `checkAuthComplete` that `isLoggedIn` should be a boolean, so you have to provide it in one way or another